# How do i get directory path, given a file name in Lua, which is platform independent

Tags: lua

If file is `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`, output should be directory name `/etc/haproxy`.

Currently i am using

```
file = "/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg"
sep = "/"
file:match("(.*"..sep..")")
```

But it is not platform independent and would fail on Windows, since the path separator is different. So is there a platform agnostic way of achieving this, with using lfs module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`package.config:sub(1,1)` gives you the path separator for the platform in which Lua is running. See the [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.config).

Comment: Both separators are valid on Windows.  Examples: `file = io.open'C:/Python27/README.txt'` and `os.execute'"C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe"'`. But `package.config:sub(1,1)` gives only backslash.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff re: `both separators on WIndows` I think you meant to show:  `file = io.open'C:/Python27/README.txt'` and `os.execute'"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"'`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure if you want to *parse* the path or *use* the path in a platform-independent way, but to parse you can use `[\\/]` pattern instead of `/`, which will match different types of path separators:

```
print(file:match("(.*[\\/])"))
```

If you want to open/access files using those paths, then using `/` as the path separator will work with Lua API on Windows.

Comment: Backslash should not be inside pattern for Linux: `local pattern_for_separator = "[/"..package.config:sub(1,1).."]"`